# why O(1) != O(log(n)) ? for n=[integer, long, ...]

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

for example, say n = Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2^123 then O(log(n)) = 32 and 123 so a small integer. isn't it O(1) ?

what is the difference ? I think, the reason is O(1) is constant but O(log(n)) not. Any other ideas ?

Comment: You're right. Even though, in practice, `O(log(n))` is very small, it still grows with relation to the size of the input, so it's not `O(1)`.

Comment: I'm wonder for(1, bignumber) for integers, long or any other primite types if their log is O(1)? beucase they are not big big enough

Comment: I think you are confusing a couple different ideas here.  When someone says O(logn) they aren't referring to the log math operation, they are referring to running time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `n` is bounded above, then complexity classes involving `n` make no sense. There is no such thing as "in the limit as 2^123 approaches infinity", except in the old joke that "a pentagon approximates a circle, for sufficiently large values of 5".

Generally, when analysing the complexity of code, we pretend that the input size isn't bounded above by the resource limits of the machine, even though it is. This does lead to some slightly odd things going on around `log n`, since if `n` has to fit into a fixed-size int type, then `log n` has quite a small bound, so the bound is more likely to be useful/relevant.

So sometimes, we're analysing a slightly idealised version of the algorithm, because the actual code written cannot accept arbitrarily large input.

For example, your average quicksort formally uses Theta(log n) stack in the worst case, obviously so with the fairly common implementation that call-recurses on the "small" side of the partition and loop-recurses on the "big" side. But on a 32 bit machine you can arrange to in fact use a fixed-size array of about 240 bytes to store the "todo list", which might be less than some other function you've written based on an algorithm that formally has O(1) stack use. The morals are that implementation != algorithm, complexity doesn't tell you anything about small numbers, and any specific number is "small".

If you want to account for bounds, you *could* say that, for example, your code to sort an array is O(1) running time, because the array has to be below the size that fits in your PC's address space, and hence the time to sort it is bounded. However, you will fail your CS assignment if you do, and you won't be providing anyone with any useful information :-)

Comment: thanks, good point !. So can I say that for integers it is no sense(log(n)) it is O(1) ?

Comment: @hilal: what do you mean, "for integers"? "Integers" means "whole numbers". The function which maps an integer `n -> log n` certainly is not O(1).

Comment: @Steve: I assumed Java integers that bounden with Integer.MAX_VALUE. sorry for misconception

Comment: @hilal: Yes, technically you can say "for fixed-width integers as input, algorithms that have a runtime of `log(n)` are in O(1)" because the input is bounded. However it's important to realize that you can just as easily say the same thing if you replace `log(n)` with `n^2` or even `2^n`. If you have bounded input, everything is `O(1)`.

Comment: @sepp2k: yes, hence my example of sorting an array. I could just as well have used travelling salesman.

Comment: @sepp2K Great comment! Ideally would have liked to see that as part of an answer!

Comment: Even if log(n) never gets enormous, there is still a pretty good range available -- enough to determine the relative efficientcy of your algorithm in a particular regime.  E.g., for sorting, you can plot `N` (on a log scale...) vs. `runtime/(N log N)` to see the relative efficiency when sorting tens, thousands, millions, and billions of records.

Comment: @comingstorm: sure. By plotting running time against input size you get an idea of how running time grows, which is what most people (ab-)use big-O notation for.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously if you know that the input will always have a fixed number of elements, the algorithm will always run in constant time. Big-O notation is used to denote *worse-case* running time, which describes the limit when the number of elements grows infinitely large.

Comment: Math.log(Integer.MAX_VALUE) is it O(1) ? i think it is O(log(n)). because one shout at me that it is NOT O(1) IT IS O(log(n)) :)

Comment: Big-O doesn't describe the limit when the number of elements grows infinitely large, it describes the limiting factor.  "Worst-case" means an input which results in the worst possible behavior for an algorithm.  So quicksort, for example, can run in O(n^2) time depending on the input and the pivot selection algorithm.

Comment: @hilal: `Math.log(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` is a number. Big-O analysis applies to functions of a variable (which we can call n).

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `n` isn't fixed.  The idea behind Big-O notation is to get an idea of how the size of the input effects the running time (or memory usage).  So if an algorithm always takes the same amount of time, whether n = 1 or n = Integer.MAX_VALUE, we say it is `O(1)`.  If the algorithm takes a unit of time longer each time the input size doubles, then we say it is `O(logn)`.

Edit: to answer your specific question on the difference between O(1) and O(logn), I'll give you an example.  Let's say we want an algorithm that will find the min element in an unsorted array.  One approach is to go through each element and keep track of the current min.  Another approach is to sort the array and then return the first element.

The first algorithm is O(n), and the second algorithm is O(nlogn).  So let's say we start with an array of 16 elements.  The first algorithm will run in time 16, the second algorithm will run in time 16*4.  If we increase it to 17, then it becomes 17 and 17*4.  We might naively say that the second algorithm takes 4 times as long as the first algorithm (if we treat the logn component as constant).

But let's look at what happens when our array contains 2^32 elements.  Now the first algorithm takes 2^32 time to complete, where our second algorithm takes 32*2^32 time to complete.  It takes 32 times as long.  Yes, it's a small difference, but it is still a difference.  If the first algorithm takes 1 minute, the second algorithm will take over half an hour!

Comment: so log(n) for n = 1 or n = Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2^bignumber is O(1) ?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  However the algorithm used to computer logarithms might not be constant-time.  2^n is simple though - make the nth bit 1 (and all the rest zero).

Answer (score 3):

I think you will get a better idea if it is called **`O(n^0)`**.

It is a **scaling function** depending on the input variable `N`. It is a function, not number, you should never assume any number for the variable `N`.

It is just like that you say that a function `f(x)` is 3 because `f(100) = 3`, it is wrong. It is a function, not any particular number. A constant function `f(x) = 1` is still a function, it will never equal to another function `g(x) = N`, i.e. `g(x)=f(x)`

Answer (score 2):

Its the growth rate that you want to look at. O(1) implies no growth at all. While O(logn) does have growth. Even though the growth is small it is still growth.

Answer (score 1):

You’re not thinking big enough. Any algorithm that runs on a computer will either run forever or terminate after some small number of steps — since the computer is only a finite state machine, you cannot write algorithms that run for an arbitrary amount of time and then terminate. By that argument, Big-O notation is only theoretical and has no purpose in a real-life computer program. Even `O(2^n)` hits an upper limit at `O(2^INT_MAX)`, which is equivalent to `O(1)`.

Realistically, though, Big-O *can* help you out if you know the constant factors. Even if an algorithm has an upper bound of `O(log n)`, and `n` can have 32 bits, that could mean the difference between a request taking 1 second and 32 seconds.

Comment: I asked only for integers, long and like that well known data types. Obviously, I know the difference between O(log(n)) and O(1) but it is small enough that we can say O(1) for the data types mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

Big-O shows how running time (or memory, etc) *changes* as the size of problem changes.
When size of the problem gets 10 times bigger, an O(n) solution takes 10 times as long, an O(log(n)) solution takes a bit longer, and an O(1) solution takes the same time: O(1) means 'changes as fast as constant 1', but constants don't change.

Familiarize yourself with the [big-O notation in a bit more detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: We are in the same side. I know that O(1) is constant but I'm confused with the small value of O(log(n)). thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why you leave "O(n)" in, and consider to drop "O(log n)".  They **both** are "constants": the former is less than 32, and the latter is less than 2<sup>32</sup>.  But you nevertheless have a natural feeling that you can't call O(n) O(1).

However, if `log(n) < 32`, it means that O(n*logn) algorithm works **thirty two times slower** than its O(n) version.  Big enough to write "log*n"s?

Comment: Well, it means that an algorithm with runtime `K * log n * n` runs up to 32 times slower than an algorithm with runtime `K * n`, where both have the same value of K. To transform an algorithm from `O(n log n)` to `O(n)`, you're probably making changes that are significant enough to change the constant: perhaps even to increase it by a factor of more than 32.